# Unexpected behavior of find -exec

Tags: bash, sed, find

I found an unexpected to me behavior of "find -exec" bash command and I would appreciate some interpretation. The same job can be done with "for file_name in `find ....`; do...." loop, so the question is why it doesn't work with -exec option of find.

There are two folders (SRC/ and src/) with the same set of files. I want to compare the files in these folders:

```
find src/ -type f -exec sh -c "diff {} `echo {} | sed 's/src/SRC/'`" \;
```

this, however, doesn't compare the files... Due to some reason sed command doesn't make the the substitution. If there is only one file, e.g., "a", in each of this folders then a command

```
find src/ -type f -exec sh -c "echo {} `echo {} | sed 's/src/SRC/'`" \;
```

outputs

```
src/a src/a
```

if one does a similar thing in bash, all the following commands give the same result (SRC/a):

```
echo src/a | sed 's/src/SRC/'
echo `echo src/a | sed 's/src/SRC/'`
sh -c "echo src/a | sed 's/src/SRC/'"
sh -c "echo `echo src/a | sed 's/src/SRC/'`"
```

but if this commands are supplied to "find -exec ..." the outputs are different:

```
find src/ -type f -exec bash -c "echo {} | sed 's/src/SRC/'" \;
```

gives "SRC/a"

and

```
find src/ -type f -exec bash -c "echo `echo {} | sed 's/src/SRC/'`" \;
```

gives "src/a"

Is that the expected behavior?

Comment: Why don't you use `diff -r SRC src`?

Comment: Escape `\`` as `\\``

Comment: @Michael that is a good point, but it doesn't answer my question. To answer your question: originally I wanted to get at the end something evoking   emacs -q --eval '(ediff-merge-files "file2" "file2")', but realized that there is something wrong with find... Then reduced to this example....

Comment: If the shell command is way too long, then the better option is to a function.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes for `sh -c` for the script is interpreted by your shell first. And Pass the filename as an argument for `sh` instead of using `{}` inside the quotes:

```
find src/ -type f -exec sh -c 'diff "$1" "$(printf "%s\n" "$1" | sed "s/src/SRC/")"' _ {} \;
```

Or with bash:

```
find src/ -type f -exec bash -c 'diff "$1" "${1/src/SRC}"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: I liked the second method +1

Comment: You don't really need Bash in this very specific case: `find src/ -type f -exec sh -c 'diff "$1" "SRC${1#src}"' _ {} \;`